# How to combine css with selectors

Tags: css

I need to clean up my CSS file and remove some bloat.  I know it's possible to combine classes and ids by separating them with commas.  However, I'm not sure how to go about combining them when they have more complex selectors like the ones below.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

```
body #gform_wrapper_14 .gform_footer input[type=submit] {
    border-radius:0px;
    background:#e89d53;
}
body #gform_wrapper_15 .gform_footer input[type=submit] {
    border-radius:0px;
    background:#e89d53;
}
body #gform_wrapper_17 .gform_footer input[type=submit] {
    border-radius:0px;
    background:#e89d53;
}
```

or

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 641px) {
    body #gform_wrapper_14 { 
      max-width: 80%;
      margin: 0 auto;
     }
    body #gform_wrapper_15 { 
      max-width: 80%;
      margin: 0 auto;
     }
    body #gform_wrapper_17 { 
      max-width: 80%;
      margin: 0 auto;
     }
    .hor-address {
        width:500px;
    }
}
```

**Clarification**:  I have multiple #gform_wrapper_xx objects (generated by 3rd party Wordpress plugin) and but I don't want to change all of them.  I just want to change these 3.

Comment: Have you tried using a comma? Can you paste what you tried when you used a comma and what the result was?

Comment: @Charlie, I'm pretty lousy at CSS and honestly didn't have a clue of where to start.

Comment: @Trebor you're downvoting good answers or answers that are 'wrong' because they don't account for information you omitted from the question. It would be helpful to update the question and supply a comment why that answer doesn't help with your question. Additionally, you seem to have downvoted 'the correct answer' by johannchopin; can you explain why (as a comment to that answer)?

Comment: @johannchopin, sorry.  I didn't downvote any of the answers.  If someone has admin rights, and it shows that I downvoted anything, please let me know so I can change my password.

Comment: @Charlie sorry.  I didn't downvote any of the answers.  I appreciate everyone's input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As simple has that:

```css
body #gform_wrapper_14 .gform_footer input[type=submit],
body #gform_wrapper_15 .gform_footer input[type=submit],
body #gform_wrapper_17 .gform_footer input[type=submit] {
    border-radius:0px;
    background:#e89d53;
}
```

and that:

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 641px) {
    body #gform_wrapper_14,
    body #gform_wrapper_15,
    body #gform_wrapper_17 { 
      max-width: 80%;
      margin: 0 auto;
     }

    .hor-address {
        width:500px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  That was as simple as it looks.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: @Trebor Not a problem ;)

Answer (score 2):

To don't generate the same css bloat do:

```
body .gform_footer input[type=submit] {
    border-radius:0px;
    background:#e89d53;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Unfortunately, I have other .gform_footer objects that I don't want changed.  Won't this change all of them too?

Answer (score -1):

You can do your code cleaner using modern sass(scss). The code will be:

```
body{
   #gform_wrapper_14{
      .gform_footer{
         input[type=submit] {
            border-radius:0px;
            background:#e89d53;
         }
      }
   }
   #gform_wrapper_15{
      @extend #gform_wrapper_14;
   }
   #gform_wrapper_17{
      @extend #gform_wrapper_14;
   }
}
```

Comment: This make it easier to *write* but still generates the same CSS bloat when compiled.

Comment: @Pauline_D you are right. I have added the solution above.

Answer (score -1):

Since all of your target elements are prefixed. You can use an attribute selector to cut down on redundancy. By using something like this `[id^="gform_wrapper_"]` you essentially target all of the elements with an id that starts with `gform_wrapper_`

You can read more about attribute selectors [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

```css
[id^="gform_wrapper_"] input[type=submit] {
  border-radius: 0px;
  background: #e89d53;
}
```

```html
<div id="gform_wrapper_14">
  <div class=".gform_footer">
    <input type="submit">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="gform_wrapper_15">
  <div class=".gform_footer">
    <input type="submit">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="gform_wrapper_16">
  <div class=".gform_footer">
    <input type="submit">
  </div>
</div>
```